# Can I rewire my ceiling fan to make it move faster?

Tags: electrical, wiring, fans, power

I installed a fan outside and it has no light, just a fan. It does have remote though. I capped off the red wire and used white, black and green. The fan at its highest setting does not move very fast and does not put off much wind.

If  I  switched the black wire to the red wire will that help, or will hooking both the red and black together give it more power?

Comment: Are you using the speed selector built into the fan (if applicable), or only the speed selector on the remote?

Comment: NOT SURE .. I HOOKED UP WHITE TO WHITE BLACK TO BLACK AND GREEN TO GREEN AND CAPED OFF THE RED AND ITS SLOW AS HELL..THOUGHT I SAW SOME WHERE IF I HOOKED UP THE RED WIRE ALSO TO THE BLACK IT WOULD ADD VOLTAGE AND MAKE IT FASTER

Comment: THE REMOTE DOES HAVE SOME LITTLE SWITCHES INSIDE ON THE BACK THAT ARE NUMBERED 1-4.. I TRIED MESSING WITH THOSE TO SEE IF ANY THING CHANGED AND GOT NO RESULTS

Comment: Travis please take caps lock off. What is the make / model of fan?

Comment: sorry i dont have that info on hand . i am at work

Answer (score 6):

If the fan has a pull chain as well as the remote the pullchain MUST be on high speed. The remote control only slows the fan down.

Bottom line is no, you cannot re-wire a ceiling fan like this to make it go faster.

Comment: Hot wiring the existing fan wouldn't increase the rpm but if replacing the motor with a different size/model could be considered re-wiring which would increase the rpm.

Comment: First off, replacing the motor is NOT "re-wiring" it. Second off, replacing the motor is not an option. These things are almost all built in China to certain specs. It's not like different size motors are options when buying, so fitting a larger motor would be akin to re-building the fan from scratch.

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing, its not a smart idea to try it.  I was just saying its physically possible and there might be some stupid enough to try but definitely not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Have you read the manufacturer's documentation?

The switches in the remote likely are for setting the transmitters frequency, and have nothing to do with fan speed.

Usually fans have a speed selector switch  (pull chain) that allows you to select LOW, MED, HIGH, or OFF.  If that switch is in the LOW setting, that's as fast as the fan will spin despite the remote setting.

Changing the wiring will likely have no affect, as both wires are likely at the same voltage potential. However, it's possible (though not likely) that the two hot wires are connected to opposite legs of the service, and connecting them together would create a short-circuit.

Start by reading the manufacturer's documentation. If you still can't figure it out, use a volt or multimeter to test the voltage between the black and white wires. If you get 120 volts (or close to it), there's a problem with the fan. If you get much lower voltage, test between the red and white wires.